# jQuery/jQTouch - How do you code a toggle button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqtouch

I'm almost finished my Document Manager's project, but I have been asked to add in Toggle buttons. I have already linked the javascript and css code but am stuck with the html code. I know to put the

```
  <input type = 'checkbox' .... />
```

can anyone help fill in the rest? I'm really stuck.

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the clarification. to create a toggle button like this:

http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?num=10&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=CfXL9cv8l0CfvM:&imgrefurl=http://mitchjinfo.deviantart.com/art/iPhone-Toggle-Button-173878367&docid=KCfqyS-NlBl4eM&imgurl=http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/215/2/0/iPhone_Toggle_Button_by_mitchjinfo.png&w=400&h=300&ei=ffJqUMnTOcP80QXosYCwDA&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=1&sig=117831312973390827386&page=1&tbnh=136&tbnw=224&start=0&ndsp=23&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:71&tx=115&ty=55

you can use code that looks something like this:

```
<div id="toggleImage">
    <img id="toggleOn" class="toggle" src="on.jpg" />
    <img id="toggleOff" class="toggle" src="off.jpg" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).sibbling('img').show();
        /* the code for whatever you are toggling goes here */
    });
});
```

the code for whatever you are toggling could include showing or hiding the Notification content or whatever it is you would like to be toggling on the page. For this on.jpg is the toggle "on" image, and off.jpg is the toggle "off" image just like the buttons for the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="clickme" name="Notifications"> Notifications<br />    
<div id="notifications">Notifications</div>

$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#notifications').toggle('slow', function() {
    // some code after completion
  });
});
```

the question marks could be replaced with some code if you would like to have some other effect, like a css change or some other event. it is not necessary so you can remove it by using this instead.

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    $('#notifications').toggle('slow');
});
```

with this code above you will have a checkbox and beside it will be the text Notifications, the .click function will be executed when someone clicks on the checkbox, when this happens the .toggle function will then be executed. What the .toggle function does is it switches the display property on the #notifications element (so your div that contains notifications). so when you click the checkbox it will switch the notifications between being hidden and visible.

As for the code, "//some code after completion" this is where you could have put further code that you would like to have executed, if you aren't sure what that is for its likely that you don't need that section so you can use the second sample code that I put. You should add this code within javascript tags on your page within your init function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //the code I showed above
});
```

Comment: Ok I think I understand that. The one I'm doing has the title 'Notifications'. Is what i would put;

   <input type = 'checkbox' id = 'clickme' name = 'Notifications'>
   <div id = 'notifications'>Notifications</div>

   $('#clickme').click(function(){
     $('#notifications').toggle('slow', function() {
       ????
     });
   });

Comment: the checkbox you are clicking does? or the div you are toggling? What do you mean by "title", does it have an ID or class?

Comment: sorry i meant to add new lines in and pressing 'enter' posts the comment. i've editied it now. 'title' would be the text the user sees. and what would an example of the code be where i put ????

Comment: @MeganSime toggle works like this: everytime the checkbox is clicked, toggle is called on the notification div to display and hide informaton inside of the div depending on the toggle state. You can add elements inside of this div and set the display: none initially to hide until the corresponding checkbox is checked.

Comment: right ok. so where you put the //some code after completion do i put...? i'm sorry but the function is confusing me and Ben thanks so much for your comment but that just confused me more.

Comment: @MeganSime sorry for the confusion! Just thought i'd help you understand the jQuery method for future practice :/

Comment: thanks @Ben I integrated your explanation to help others who might view this page

Comment: Ben it's fine i know you were trying to help and i really appreciate it :) I have the checkbox displaying onscreen but i want the toggle button to be like the one ine iphone and ipad etc. i found code in jquery.js referring to a toggle button and but don't know how to call it and a css document (theme.css) to make a toggle button like that. How do i change the checkbox into that kind on toggle button?

Comment: do you have an example website that I can check out on my iphone to see the type of toggle button you are referring to?

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?num=10&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=CfXL9cv8l0CfvM:&imgrefurl=http://mitchjinfo.deviantart.com/art/iPhone-Toggle-Button-173878367&docid=KCfqyS-NlBl4eM&imgurl=http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/215/2/0/iPhone_Toggle_Button_by_mitchjinfo.png&w=400&h=300&ei=ffJqUMnTOcP80QXosYCwDA&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=1&sig=117831312973390827386&page=1&tbnh=136&tbnw=224&start=0&ndsp=23&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:71&tx=115&ty=55
this is a picture of the kind of toggle button

Answer (score 0):

Without going out of your educational scope of this project, I suggest starting off with the basics below. The exact button you want is included in the iOS framework class **UISwitch**, but let's not get way over our heads here :)

Start of with creating the front-end html structure, include the css and javascript links in your  tag, create a javascript folder and inside, a .js file.

It's common to see buttons/check boxes used in any type of form where a button click event is triggered, and you need to determine which buttons are selected:

```
<head>
<link href="yourstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="~/javascript/mobilejavascript.js" type="text/javascript" />
</head>

<input type="radio" name="radio1" class="radio_form" value="male"/>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio_form" value="female"/>

on submit of form...

var isMale = false;

$('.radio_form').each(function(){
     //perform some check or store information
     if($(this).val('male') == true)
     {
         isMale = true;
     }
     //and so on...
});
```

Now in your style sheet (.css):

```
.radio_form {
  //style properties will go here, such as radius, border, width, height, etc..
}
```

This should help you get started in the right direction if this is your criteria

Comment: ok...i think i understand what the code means...does this create a toggle button like on the iphone?

Comment: yes, it creates a default radio button. The <input> element has been rendered to create different types of input, such as checkbox, radio button, label, textbox, etc.. You can add attribute class (as above) and in your style sheet, style the radio button to your liking.

Comment: so if instead of class = 'radio_form' i put class = 'toggle', and in the css document there is a toggle attribute it would format the button as the code in the css document tells it too? am i right or am i just confused? thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: are you developing this for mobile device or website?

Comment: it's a mobile web app so sort of both

Comment: I'll continue to update my code for you as we go along, but it may not be till later. For now, just work on getting the above set up in your web app directory.